# If I want to return a list of strings from a function, should I return a raw array or a std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am an inexperienced C++ programmer and I am a little bit confused. I have a function that needs to calculate some values at run time and return the values in an array.

I was actually going for a pointer to a string array and I wanted to return that pointer (my array is global so it wont go out of scope after returning from the function). Since I don’t know the number of values in advance, I don’t want to initialize a big array. (Also, is it a bad practice? My teacher told me that its not good to initialize an array of size 512 like `new int[512]` but I don’t know how else I would allocate memory for an array?). I read a lot and it seems like vectors are a good solution to this as their size can be increased or decreased during the run time and everyone seems to be favouring them, but I have never used vectors. Also, I am using strings everywhere else and I don’t want to deal with the vector to string conversions.

So which one is a good approach here?

Comment: A code sample is better than a description.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to convert between a string and a vector ? Do you return an array of chars ?

Comment: Arrays must have a fixed size at compile-time

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in C++ it's probably better to return a `std::vector` of strings than a raw pointer to an array. The `std::vector` manages its own memory, so there's a lower chance of a memory leak. `std::vector` also knows its size, so it's safer (otherwise, how would you know how many elements you returned?) and can be used in range-based for loops. On top of that, the `std::vector` also supports insertions and deletions, making it easier to then transform later on.

Answer (score 1):

Please read :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

The vector is easier to manage and offers more functionality. A vector makes it also clear that you are returning a collection of element. A pointer is not always an array which may lead to errors in treating the return value. Arrays can be good if you have a low memory system and need to manage every byte you have.

With a vector you simply need to iterate over your vector to get all of your results. Something like this :

```
std::vector<std::string> calculateSomethingFunction()
{
    std::vector<std::string> myresult;
    myresult.push_back("I am a string");
    return myresult;
}

void readResults(const std::vector<std::string>& results)
{
     std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = results.begin();
     for(; it != results.end(); ++it)
     {
        std::string currentResult = *it;
     }
}
```

Comment: And if you're using C++11 (or newer), the hideous `std::vector<std::string>::iterator` can be replaced with `auto` - or the whole loop with `for (auto&& s: results) { /* do something with s */}`.  Enjoy your C++ journey!

Comment: @Toby Speight Very true, C++ 11 offers a lot of new functionality that one should definitely take advantage of.  The features available may depend on your compiler though.

Answer (score -1):

You should return a `std:vector <std:string>` in a function to return a copy of the element. Instead you can give your `std:vector<std:string>` to the function with reference in order to change directly it.